# producing "unhandled exception X at memory location Y" when checking every pixel of an grayscale image

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am trying to solve a problem where I have to check every pixel from a 640x480 cv::Mat (Greyscale Video Image -> cv::Mat MainImageSW (global)) and check if the pixel above, below, to the left and to the right is equal or below the Threshholdvalue ( GetTreshholdSW() ).

My target matrix XY_ThreshholdMat is also 640x480 and set equal to Matrix255 which is initialized with"255".
If the requirements meet I set the pixel of my new Mat "XY_ThreshholdMat" to "0" in that location.
The aim is to have every pixel which meets the req. to be black and the others white.

To do so I wrote the following code:

```
void GraphicsView_PP::Fill_XY_TreshholdMat()
{
    cv::Mat Matrix255(GetPixmapWidth(), GetPixmapHeight(), CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(255)); 
    XY_ThreshholdMat = Matrix255;
    
    for (int y = 1; y < (GetPixmapHeight()-1); y++)
    {
        for (int x = 1; x < (GetPixmapWidth()-1); x++)
        {
            if ((MainImageSW.at<uchar>(y, x)) <= GetTreshholdSW())
            {

                if ((MainImageSW.at<uchar>((y + 1), x) <= GetTreshholdSW()) &&  
                    (MainImageSW.at<uchar>((y - 1), x) <= GetTreshholdSW()) &&
                    (MainImageSW.at<uchar>(y, (x + 1)) <= GetTreshholdSW()) && 
                    (MainImageSW.at<uchar>(y, (x - 1)) <= GetTreshholdSW()))            
                {
                    XY_ThreshholdMat.at<uchar>(y, x) = 0;  
                }
            }
        }
    }

    QImage Image((uchar*)XY_ThreshholdMat.data, XY_ThreshholdMat.cols, XY_ThreshholdMat.rows, XY_ThreshholdMat.step, QImage::Format_Grayscale8);
    QPixmap Pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(Image);
    ui.graphicsView_Bild->UpdateStream(Pixmap);
    cv::waitKey(5000); 
}
```

Because I am checking the pixels above, below, to the left and to the right I start both for-loops at X/Y = 1 and let it end to (MaxWidth-1) and (MaxHeight-1).

After checking every individual pixel I want to save the new Mat where every Match is a "0" and everything else is "255" to a Pixmap and display it in my custom QGraphicsView element.

Once I run the code I get the typical "unhandled exception X at memory location Y" error but I dont know why..

Also: I am rather new at programming and I know that the way the code is designed is not the most efficient way. All that matters is that it works..

Anyone having an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: XY_ThreshholdMat is :   "cv::Mat XY_ThreshholdMat(640, 480, CV_8UC1)"

Comment: Why are you casting here: `(uchar*)XY_ThreshholdMat.data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cv::Mat Matrix255(GetPixmapWidth(), GetPixmapHeight(), ...
```

should be

```
cv::Mat Matrix255(GetPixmapHeight(), GetPixmapWidth(), ...
```

Because of this mistake you access the elements out of bounds and your program therefore has undefined behavior.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't resist: [I hate a Tight Hat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1I2xNdoQXM4) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff :-D Yeah, I like my roomy hat !